# pandas data frame effeciently remove duplicates and keep records largest int value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame with two columns NAME, and VALUE, where NAME contains duplicates and VALUE contains INTs. I would like to efficiently drop duplicates records of column NAME while keeping the record with the largest VALUE. I figured out how to do it will two steps, sort and drop duplicates, but I am new to pandas and am curious if there is a more efficient way to achieve this with the query function?

```py
import pandas
import io
import json

input = """
KEY      VALUE
apple    0
apple    1
apple    2
bannana  0
bannana  1
bannana  2
pear     0
pear     1
pear     2
pear     3
orange   0
orange   1
orange   2
orange   3
orange   4
"""

df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(input), delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
df[['KEY','VALUE']].sort_values(by=['VALUE']).drop_duplicates(subset='KEY', keep='last')
dicty = dict(zip(df['KEY'], df['VALUE']))
print(json.dumps(dicty, indent=4))
```

running this yields the expected output:

```py
{
    "apple": 2,
    "bannana": 2,
    "pear": 3,
    "orange": 4
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this transformation with pandas?

Answer (score 2):

```
df = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(input), delim_whitespace=True, header=0)
df.groupby('KEY')['VALUE'].max()
```

If your input needs to be a dictionary, just add `to_dict()` :

```
df.groupby('KEY')['VALUE'].max().to_dict()
```

Comment: this worked for me: df.groupby('KEY')['VALUE'].max().to_dict(). i got an TypeError when I used the 'index' parameter.

Comment: Great, removed it

Answer (score 1):

Also you can try:

```
[*df.groupby('KEY',sort=False).last().to_dict().values()][0]
```

---

```
{'apple': 2, 'bannana': 2, 'pear': 3, 'orange': 4}
```

Comment: so here i can see that we are sorting on key, getting the last value, and converting to a dict. Seems like similar logical steps to my initial approach with the addition of the groupby function. Which is pretty nice for this. But I am getting confused what the `*df` is doing and why do we need to get the first element of the resulting list?

Comment: @AidanMelen sorting and getting last is as good as max, please refer Vincent output which gets max. `*` is to splat `.values()` from a dict to a list

Comment: i see. i have only ever used list(dicty.values())